# gulp-babel and the strict mode

Tags: javascript, gulp, babeljs, bundling-and-minification, gulp-babel

I use the "gulp-babel" before uglifying my js files. The module blocks the minification because a third party js script is not "strict mode" compilant.

```
// Include gulp
var gulp = require('gulp');
var baseDir = "./";
var jsources = [
    "sites/**/js/*.js",
    "!sites/**/js/*.min.js"
];

// Include Plugins
var jshint = require('gulp-jshint');
var babel = require('gulp-babel');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');


// Minify JS
gulp.task('scripts', function () {
    return gulp.src(jsources, { base: baseDir })
        .pipe(babel({
            presets: [
                ['env', { modules: false }]
            ]
        }))
        .pipe(uglify().on('error', function (e) { console.log(e); }))
        .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(baseDir));
});
```

As result I obtain an error because a js file is not *strict mode* compilant:
[image]

I don't want to modify that third-party file to make it *strict mode* compilant. How can I disable that check for that file or another similar files?

Just now the minification is blocked because of that kind of files...

I tried

- to install the ["transform-remove-strict-mode"](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-remove-strict-mode) plugin and then do

  ```
  .pipe(babel({
      "presets": ["env"],
      "plugins": ["transform-remove-strict-mode"]
  }))
  ```
- I also tried the

  ```
  .pipe(babel({
      presets: [
          ["es2015", { "modules": false }]
      ]
  }))
  ```

but the output is still the same...

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`ignore`](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/api/#options) option to avoid transpiling your 3rd party code. The `transform-remove-strict-mode` plugin doesn't work because it's already too late.

Comment: so, there is no option to *remove the strict mode*, but to ignore files?!... there are actually a lot of 3rd party files in the solution that does not fit the strict mode, so it takes a lot to identify and list them all...

Comment: Then use `only` (it's the opposite of `ignore`), an inclusive list

Comment: Thanks, the `ignore` works, but I think better is to include these files, just remove the "strict mode", if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try gulp-uglify with mangle option

```
uglify({ mangle: false })
```

Comment: do you mean, disable *mangle* instead of using *babel*, or using both?

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure.
 Please try changing to 
`presets: [
    ['es2015', {modules: false}]
]`

Comment: I tried, the same output... (see my edits)... thanks anyway !

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's too late but you could try to do it this way:

```
gulp.task('foo_task', () => {

gulp.src('foo/src/path')

    .pipe(concat('foo_file.js')
    .pipe(babel({ presets: ['env'] }))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('foo/dist/path'))

    .pipe(concat([ '/dist/path', 'foo/src/path' ]))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('foo/dist/path'))

});
```

Comment: I've tried to change the gulp-babel options too but didn't work.